# What is the procedure for Minimum contiguous sum with atmost K swaps

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array say `{-1,2,3,4,-3,-2,1,5}`

Now I would like to find the minimum contiguous sum subarray for the given array with atmost `K` swaps.

In the array above the minimum contiguous sum is `-5` and subarray is `{-3,-2}`

Say for `K=1` How should I swap the elements

1. Should I swap the left element of the sub array i,e; swaping element `4` at `a[3]`  which is left to it with `-1` (again with which number (sub question pops up in my mind)?

   a. whether the lowest of the the remaining elements (with any sorting technique of the remaining elements excluding subarrays). If I do this  I will swap `-1` with `4` and the min sum will be `{-1,-3,-2}`
   As per "***atmost***" `K` swaps I can return this the subarray with only one swap even how long the array is
2. Should I swap the element `1` at the postion `a[6]` with `-1` and get the sub array with min sum as `{-3,-2,-1}`. Again following the same question at point a above.

This whole process I would like to do with recursion. As I am dealing with arrays with `N` integers. Which is best approach I should follow recursion or iteration?

Comment: If you swap -1 and 4 you get subarray {-3,-1,-3,-2}.

Comment: What is the scale of `n` and `k`?

Comment: Hi Amit the scale of N can we vary depending on user , if I give K as 2, but   we see above that we had achieved the subarray in some way or the other in only one swap..

Comment: What's the maximum sizes you want to allow? A BFS will solve this problem, but will be infeasible for large values of `k`.

Comment: @ Andreas How should I swap -1 and 4 and how do I decide at which swap it should be out of say k=2 swaps.

Comment: @amit: Now we will take short input. but I think our algorithm should handle large arrays too. OK I got it that its infeasible for large values of large values of K, then how do I go for large values of K. Here we will take short input and atmost K swaps and k can also be small

Comment: @ andreas and Amit just edited the input and question.

Comment: `@amit: Now we will take short input.` This is not [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/): to improve the question, edit it (preferably not to the point of invalidating existing answers). If you want to ask something else, post another question. If it is related to an existing one, [link that](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links).

Answer (score 1):

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class TestClass {

```
   static Scanner scanner;
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {


    scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=scanner.nextInt();

    while(t>0){
        t--;
    int n=scanner.nextInt();
    int k=scanner.nextInt();
    int[] array=new int[n];
     for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
     {
        array[i]=scanner.nextInt();
    }
    int ans=findingMinimumSumSubarray(array,k);
     System.out.println(ans);
    }


}

public static int findingMinimumSumSubarray(int[] values, int k) {
 int len = values.length;
 int res = values[0]; 
 for (int l = 0; l < len; l++) {
     for (int r = l; r < len; r++) {
         List<Integer> A= new ArrayList<Integer>();
         List<Integer> B = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
         int abc = 0; 
         for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
             if (i >= l && i <= r) {
              A.add(values[i]);
                 abc += values[i];
             } else {
                 B.add(values[i]);
             }
         }

         Collections.sort(A);

         Collections.sort(B);
         Collections.reverse(B);
         res = Math.min(res, abc); 
         for (int t = 1; t <= k; t++) {

             if (t > A.size() || t > B.size()) break;

             abc -= A.get(A.size() - t);
             abc += B.get(B.size() - t);
             res = Math.min(res, abc);
         }
     }
 }
 return res;
```

}
}

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue